# prove that $u_n$/$u_{n +1}$ ≥ 1.

Tags: real-analysis

I have to use Bernoulli's inequality to prove that $u_n$/$u_{n +1}$ ≥ 1.

Bernoulli's inequality: (1+x)$^n$ ≥ 1 + nx $\forall n ∈ N$.

And $u_n$ = (1 + 1/n)$^{n+1}$

What is the best way to prove this? I know how to prove it WITHOUT Bernoulli's inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the inequality you need to prove as $(\frac{n+1}{n})^{n+1} \geq (\frac{n+2}{n+1})^{n+2}$ or even as $\frac{((n+1)^{2n+2})}{(n(n+2))^{n+1}} \geq \frac{n+2}{n+1}$

Now $\frac{((n+1)^{2n+2})}{(n(n+2))^{n+1}} = (\frac{n^2 + 2n + 1}{n^2+2n})^{n+1}$ which, by Bernoulli is greater or equal to $1+ \frac{n+1}{n^2+2n}$ which is greater than $1+\frac{1}{n+1}$ because $(n+1)^2 > n^2+2n$